# Coroutine scope for @ActivityRetained classes?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, dagger-hilt

If I have a class in my app annotated with `@ActivityRetained` it makes sense to able to access a *coroutine scope* that will be canceled appropriately. It would be similar to the `viewModelScope` in a `ViewModel`.

Is this something that can be done or is it something that still needs to be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same problem but finally I found a solution [here](https://github.com/shizheng233/CopyMangaJava/blob/acb49d9ecdeab45b99cc9adcba8fc6b2af493e22/app/src/main/java/com/shicheeng/copymanga/util/RetainedLifecycleCoroutineScope.kt#L10)

You can create your own `CoroutineScope` with passed lifecycle:

```
class RetainedLifecycleCoroutineScope(
    val lifecycle: RetainedLifecycle,
) : CoroutineScope, RetainedLifecycle.OnClearedListener {

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main.immediate

    init {
        lifecycle.addOnClearedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        coroutineContext.cancel()
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
@ActivityRetainedScoped
class UseCase @Inject constructor(
    activityRetainedLifecycle: ActivityRetainedLifecycle,
) {
    private val coroutineScope = RetainedLifecycleCoroutineScope(activityRetainedLifecycle)
}
```